# why is price being printed twice?

Tags: java, methods

My Code:

```
package ecommerceapp;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ECommerceApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String productsCatalog = " ";
    //double price = getPrice();
    bannerPrinter();
    productsBuilder();
    boolean exists = getOrder(productsCatalog);

    if (exists == true) {
        double salesTotal = 0;
        printTotal(salesTotal);
    } else {
        System.out.println("The product not found.");
    }
    //double price = 0;
    //double tax = getTax(price);

    //getTotal(price, tax);
}

public static void bannerPrinter() {
    System.out.println("******************************************");
    System.out.println("====== Welcome to my eCommerce app! ======");
    System.out.println("******************************************");
}

public static String productsBuilder() {
    String productsCatalog = "Desk      Table     Pen       ";
    return productsCatalog;
}

public static boolean getOrder(String productsCatalog) {
    String userProduct;
    boolean exists = true;
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a product name: ");
    userProduct = scnr.nextLine();
    if (productsBuilder().toLowerCase().contains(userProduct.toLowerCase())) {
        exists = true;
        System.out.println(exists);
    } else {
        exists = false;
        System.out.println(exists);
    }
    return exists;
}

public static double getPrice() {
    double price = 1 + Math.random() * 99;
    price = Math.round(price * 100.0) / 100.0;
    System.out.println("Price is: " + price);
    return price;
}

public static double getTax(double price) {
    double tax = (0.1 * getPrice());
    tax = Math.round(tax * 100.0) / 100.0;
    System.out.println("Tax is: " + tax);
    return tax;
}

public static double getTotal(double price, double tax) {
    double salesTotal = getPrice() + getTax(price);
    return salesTotal;
}

public static void printTotal(double salesTotal) {
    double price = 0;
    double tax = 0;
    System.out.printf("Your sale total is: $%.2f", getTotal(price, tax));
    System.out.println();
}

}
```

Why is my output printing the price twice?

---

====== Welcome to my eCommerce app! ======

---

Please enter a product name: desk

true

Price is: 64.43

Price is: 85.07

Tax is: 8.51

Your sale total is: $72.94

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)

When I remove System.out.println from both getPrice and getTax, this is my output

---

====== Welcome to my eCommerce app! ======

---

Please enter a product name: desk

true

Tax is: 8.6

Your sale total is: $38.60

Comment: Don't have getter methods print anything. They should return a value and not have a side effect.

Comment: My submission will not show the price or tax, but I want the price to be generated only once,regardless.

Comment: Your code has too many problems to be answerable IMHO.  The bottom line is that you are calling things twice, which are printing twice.  Many of your methods return values which you never use.

Comment: So, someone already downvoted this one too  @HovercraftFullOfEels All I need is to print the price, the tax and the total for the user to see. If I remove println as suggested, the price and tax are not visible. The fact that the price is being generated twice means there is a problem with my method calling and I am wondering if anyone can see the issue and help me out.

Comment: Improve and clarify the question. Edit the question, with your new code and details (below the original code) showing how you've followed the advice given but are still having problems.

Answer (score 6):

because you are printing the result of getPrice. and getPrice itself is printing price so as a result, your program prints price twice. delete the "System.out.println" function in your getPrice block.

Comment: If I remove println as suggested, the price and tax are not visible to the user. The fact that the price is being generated twice means there is a problem with my method calling and I am wondering if anyone can see the issue and help me out.

Answer (score 3):

Because you call `getPrice()`, which prints the price, in both `getTax()` and `getTotal()`.

Answer (score 1):

When you call getTotal (Inside printTotal) you are calling getPrice which in itself has

`System.out.println("Price is: " + price);`

and as a result of this when you then call the getTax you are calling the getPrice again

`double tax = (0.1 * getPrice());`

which then calls the println and that is why it prints twice.

Comment: when I replace the getPrice with price here double tax = (0.1 * getPrice()), it sets price to 0 and no the price generated by getPrice. How can I use the price alone without using the whole method?

Comment: What I recommend you do is not to have the print-outs inside the get methods unless it is for debugging purposes.

Comment: What you should do is first of all remove the print-outs inside the get methods and then inside the printTotal you should get and put the price in a variable, like this `double price = getPrice()` and then you print out the price like this `System.out.println("Price is : " + price)` and then go on to the tax and do the same there and then when you get to the the total you just pass the price and tax just like you're already doing.

Comment: Hi @Jockie I made the changes you suggested and it worked, i don;t have the price as a duplicate, but the math is wrong because the price is being generated twice. This is my output now.        Please enter a product name: desk
true
Price is: $90.00
Tax is: $9.90
Your sale total is: $20.30